# Is this written in a proper java8 way?

Tags: java-8

I have a POJO where I have a `Map<String, String>` field.

I need to do the below checks.

1. Check POJO object null
2. Check `map` is null
3. Get a value from a map
4. Parse to boolean - It is not happening in the below snippet
5. Return true or false.

For negative cases in first 4 statement should lead to false value.

I have something as below.

```
Optional<Object> optional = Optional.ofNullable(event)
                            .map(Event::getAttributes)
                            .map(attrMap -> attrMap.get("restructured"));

return optional.isPresent();
```

How can I do this in Java8 way? I see that if value is null, NPE is thrown. Is there any way to do as I mentioned in the steps i.e if null return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional#orElse` is exactly what you need:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(e)
  .map(Event::getAttribute)
  .map(m -> m.get("restructured"))
  .map(Boolean::parseBoolean)
  .orElse(false);
```

If any of the steps produces `null` then result resolves to `false`.

Comment: Does `orElse` apply to all the intermediate steps? Is it correct?

Comment: @Gibbs I think my last sentence should give you the answer